# Creating an instance of the self type in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit, higher-kinded-types

I am not sure whether the title of the question is phrased correctly in Scala type terminology... I am facing a problem that is somewhat analogous to what Scala collections manage with `CanBuildFrom`.

There is a hierarchy of higher-kinded types and a parallel hierarchy of containers (not necessarily collections) of those types. An operation that, say, filters the items in the container, should return the exact type of the container that the operation is executed on, with the items filtered.

The problem I am encountering is that I can't find the right approach to restricting the implicit evidence requirement to the exact type of container to be constructed without passing the container type explicitly.

A simplified version of the setup I'm dealing with is below. I'd appreciate some advice on how to approach this issue.

```
@implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot construct a ${B} from ${A} with arguments of type ${Args}.")
trait CanConstruct[A, -Args, +B] {
  def apply(args: Args): B
}

class A1

trait C1[A <: A1] {
  def a: A
  def active: Boolean
}
trait C1s[C <: C1[A] forSome {type A <: A1}] {
  def values: Seq[C]
  // @note something like def active[From <: C1s[_]]... will find implicits
  //       but will be happy to use a super-type's implicit for a subtype's      
  def active[To[_ <: C]](implicit builder: CanConstruct[To[_], Seq[C], To[C]]): To[C] =
    builder(values.filter(_.active))
}

class C2(val a: A1, val active: Boolean) extends C1[A1]
class C2s[C <: C2](val values: Seq[C]) extends C1s[C]
object C2s {
  class C2CanConstruct[C <: C2] extends CanConstruct[C2s[_], Seq[C], C2s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]): C2s[C] = new C2s(args)
  }
  implicit def C2CanConstruct[C <: C2] = new C2CanConstruct[C]
}

class C3s[C <: C2](values: Seq[C]) extends C2s[C](values)
object C3s {
  class C3CanConstruct[C <: C2] extends CanConstruct[C3s[_], Seq[C], C3s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]): C3s[C] = new C3s(args)
  }
  implicit def C3CanConstruct[C <: C2] = new C3CanConstruct[C]
}

val a = new A1()
val cs = Seq(new C2(a, true), new C2(a, false))

// How can active pick the corresponding C?CanConstruct implicit automatically?
// i.e., new C2s(cs).active returns C2s[...] and 
//       new C3s(cs).active returns C3s[...]
new C2s(cs).active[C2s]
new C3s(cs).active[C3s]
```

**Update:**

The type member approach in the answer below is promising, but fails to handle the case where `C1` has type parameters ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ssimeonov/R5cvAo6oQ0C7wkSlLMGA4w/7)). I omitted that detail in the original question formulation with the desire to strike a balance between necessary & unnecessary complexity. When it comes to the type member approach, it seems the additional complexity is necessary.

Comment: Why not have `To` as a type parameter (to your classes, I mean)?

Comment: @user In `C1s`? It gets quite messy as, in the actual system, the types have more complicated parameterizations. I'm looking for a way to avoid this boilerplate.

Comment: @Sim *How can active pick the corresponding implicit automatically?* What do you mean? Do you want `To[_ <: C]` to be inferred? Do you want to write just `new C2s(cs).active`, `new C3s(cs).active`? Could you emphasize what's wrong with the code you posted and what is your goal?

Comment: @DmytroMitin excellent suggestion; updated.

Comment: @Sim Actually you don't constrain `To[_ <: C]`. Not only `new C2s(cs).active[C2s]`,
`new C3s(cs).active[C3s]` compile. `new C2s(cs).active[C3s]`,
`new C3s(cs).active[C2s]` do as well. This is one of the reasons why `To[_ <: C]` can't be inferred.

Comment: @Sim It's still unclear what you want with `A` and why you're using `To[_]` in `CanConstructFrom[To[_], Seq[C], To[C]]`. Could you give more details about that?

Comment: @DmytroMitin that makes sense. What pattern would you recommend for addressing the problem of creating instances of the "self type"?

Comment: @Sim I'd make `To[_ <: C]` an abstract type member of the trait `C1s` like **user** proposed in his second approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit 2: [Here's](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cUCfu4wUTyKUewt0MBpoVA) a fixed version of the [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ssimeonov/R5cvAo6oQ0C7wkSlLMGA4w/7) you linked. The problem there was that every use of `C1.T`/`C2.T` is different, so `C <: C1.T` was not necessarily the same thing as `T <: C1.T`. The link above is almost the same as Dmytro Mitin's answer so I'm not putting it here. The only thing different is that it uses `type T = C1[_]` instead of `type T = C1[A] forSome {type A <: Config}`.

An alternative without implicits:

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(
  msg = "Cannot construct a ${To} from ${From} with arguments of type ${Args}."
)
trait CanConstruct[+From, -Args, +To] {
  def apply(args: Args): To
}

class Config

trait C1[Cfg <: Config] {
  type Config = Cfg
  def config: Config
}
object C1 {
  type T = C1[_]
}
trait C1s[C <: C1.T] {
  type From <: C1s[_]
  type To[T <: C] <: C1s[T]
  def values: Seq[C]
  protected def builder: CanConstruct[From, Seq[C], To[C]]
  def filter(f: C => Boolean): To[C] =
    builder(values.filter(f))
}

class C2[Cfg <: Config](val config: Cfg, val active: Boolean) extends C1[Cfg]
object C2 {
  type T = C2[_]
}
abstract class C2s[C <: C2.T](val values: Seq[C]) extends C1s[C] {
  type From <: C2s[_]
  type To[T <: C] <: C2s[T]
}
object C2s {
  def apply[C <: C2.T](values: Seq[C]) =
    new C2s(values) { 
      type From = C2s[_]
      type To[T2 <: C] = C2s[T2] 
      val builder = new CanConstruct[C2s[_], Seq[C], RefinedC2s[C]] {
        def apply(args: Seq[C]) = C2s(args)
      }
    }
}

//Final because its type members are invariant
final class C3s[C <: C2.T](values: Seq[C]) extends C2s[C](values) {
  type From = C3s[_]
  type To[T <: C] = C3s[T]
  protected val builder = new CanConstruct[C3s[_], Seq[C], C3s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]): C3s[C] = new C3s(args)
  }
}

val cfg = new Config
val cs = Seq(new C2(cfg, true), new C2(cfg, false))

val c2s = C2s(cs).filter(_.active).filter(_.active)
val c3s = new C3s(cs).filter(_.active).filter(_.active)
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kR7JsryGTsqaUIABAGIGEw)

---

Edit: You can also make `To` an abstract type member. The issue here is that `To` will have to be abstract in `C2`, meaning that the implicit won't be found. To work around this, we can make a refined type like `type RefinedC2s[T <: C2] = C2s[T] { type To[T <: C2] = C2s[T] }`, and make an `apply` method in your companion object that returns it (you won't have to do this for `C3s`). You'll also have to make the constructor protected to make sure no one creates a `C2` with an abstract `To`.

```
trait C1 {
  def active: Boolean
}
trait C1s[C <: C1] {
  type To[T <: C] <: C1s[T]
  //R is so that it can be RefinedC2s instead of C2s
  def active[R <: To[C]](implicit builder: CanConstruct[To[_], Seq[C], R]): R = 
    builder(values.filter(_.active))
}

class C2s[C <: C2](val values: Seq[C]) extends C1s[C] {
  type To[T <: C2] <: C2s[T]
}
object C2s {
  type RefinedC2s[T <: C2] = C2s[T] { type To[T <: C2] = C2s[T] }
  def apply[C <: C2](values: Seq[C]) = new C2s(values) { type To[T <: C2] = C2s[T] }
  class C2CanConstruct[C <: C2] extends CanConstruct[C2s[_], Seq[C], RefinedC2s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]) = C2s(args)
  }
}

class C3s[C <: C2](values: Seq[C]) extends C2s[C](values) {
  type To[T <: C2] = C3s[T]
}
```

You can use it like this, and don't need to worry about casting to `RefinedC2s` each time.

```
val c2s = C2s(cs).active.active.active.active.active
val c3s = new C3s(cs).active.active
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Lf2mlLVNQjKZUziqOQQcbQ)

---

Consider making an implicit class to add `active` as an extension method. This makes it a whole lot easier than using `To` as a type parameter (or as a type member, which I previously experimented with)

Here's a naive attempt at doing this. I've removmed `a` and `A1` because they mostly just cluttered up the example. I also made `A` covariant in `CanBuildFrom` so that I could pass it `C2s[Nothing]`, etc., because I had no idea what it was supposed to do.

```
import scala.language.existentials

@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot construct a ${B} from ${A} with arguments of type ${Args}.")
trait CanConstruct[+A, -Args, B] {
  def apply(args: Args): B
}

trait C1 {
  def active: Boolean
}
trait C1s[C <: C1] {
  def values: Seq[C]
}

implicit class CsOps[C <: C1, Cs[_ <: C] <: C1s[_ <: C]](cs: Cs[C]) {
  def active(implicit builder: CanConstruct[Cs[Nothing], Seq[C], Cs[C]]): Cs[C] = 
    builder(cs.values.filter(_.active))
}

class C2(val active: Boolean) extends C1
class C2s[C <: C2](val values: Seq[C]) extends C1s[C]

object C2s {
  class C2CanConstruct[C <: C2] extends CanConstruct[C2s[Nothing], Seq[C], C2s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]): C2s[C] = new C2s(args)
  }
  implicit def C2CanConstruct[C <: C2] = new C2CanConstruct[C]
}

class C3s[C <: C2](values: Seq[C]) extends C2s[C](values)

object C3s {
  class C3CanConstruct[C <: C2] extends CanConstruct[C3s[Nothing], Seq[C], C3s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]): C3s[C] = new C3s(args)
  }
  implicit def C3CanConstruct[C <: C2] = new C3CanConstruct[C]
}

val cs = Seq(new C2(true), new C2(false))

val c2s: C2s[C2] = new C2s(cs).active
val c3s: C3s[C2] = new C3s(cs).active

c2s -> C2s(List(C2(true))): C2s[C2]
c3s -> C2s(List(C2(true))): C3s[C2]
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6eGRsKAeRvmgv2u0OePGpA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I considered this and decided against it as applying this approach to the full system would result in moving the majority behaviors related to types to implicits, which is an anti-pattern for many reasons related to usability, maintainability, etc.

Comment: @Sim I've added an alternative way to do it with type members, requiring only a little more boilerplate. Also, I would suggest using different types `From` and `To`

Comment: thank you for the additional effort: I like the type member approach. Unfortunately, the actual system is more complicated: C1 includes a type parameter that that triggers an incompatible type override error (Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ssimeonov/R5cvAo6oQ0C7wkSlLMGA4w/7). My bad for assuming that a simpler formulation of the question would be sufficient. I'll add a bounty to this question for the extra work required to tune the answer.

Comment: @Sim [This](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Y3hmPvSNT5Kal5W77nyUkA) works. Just replace `T <: C2.T` with `T <: C`

Comment: Thanks for exploring this problem further.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your updated question (with "real-world" code) try the following modified version of **@user**'s second approach with abstract type member `To`. I modified upper bounds of `To`'s parameter in `C1s` (necessary), `C2s` (necessary), `C3s` (optional) (otherwise overriding of `To` doesn't work) and made the type class `CanConstruct` covariant with respect to `To` (otherwise implicit is not found).

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot construct a ${To} from ${From} with arguments of type ${Args}.")
trait CanConstruct[+From, -Args, +To] {
  def apply(args: Args): To
}

class Config

trait C1[Cfg <: Config] {
  type Config = Cfg
  def config: Config
}
object C1 {
  type T = C1[A] forSome {type A <: Config}
}
trait C1s[C <: C1.T] {
  type To[T <: /*C1.T*/C] <: C1s[T]
  def values: Seq[C]
  def filter[R <: To[C]](f: C => Boolean)(implicit builder: CanConstruct[To[_], Seq[C], R]): R =
    builder(values.filter(f))
}

class C2[Cfg <: Config](val config: Cfg, val active: Boolean) extends C1[Cfg]
object C2 {
  type T = C2[A] forSome {type A <: Config}
}
class C2s[C <: C2.T](val values: Seq[C]) extends C1s[C] {
  type To[T <: /*C2.T*/C] <: C2s[T]
}
object C2s {
  type RefinedC2s[C <: C2.T] = C2s[C] { type To[T <: /*C2.T*/C] = C2s[T] }
  def apply[C <: C2.T](values: Seq[C]) = new C2s(values) { type To[T <: /*C2.T*/C] = C2s[T] }
  class C2CanConstruct[C <: C2.T] extends CanConstruct[C2s[_], Seq[C], RefinedC2s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]) = C2s(args)
  }
  implicit def C2CanConstruct[C <: C2.T] = new C2CanConstruct[C]
}

class C3s[C <: C2.T](values: Seq[C]) extends C2s[C](values) {
  type To[T <: /*C2.T*/C] = C3s[T]
}
object C3s {
  class C3CanConstruct[C <: C2.T] extends CanConstruct[C3s[_], Seq[C], C3s[C]] {
    def apply(args: Seq[C]): C3s[C] = new C3s(args)
  }
  implicit def C3CanConstruct[C <: C2.T] = new C3CanConstruct[C]
}

val cfg = new Config
val cs = Seq(new C2(cfg, true), new C2(cfg, false))

implicitly[CanConstruct[C2s[_], Seq[C2[Config]], C2s[C2[Config]]]]
implicitly[CanConstruct[C3s[_], Seq[C2[Config]], C3s[C2[Config]]]]

val c2s = C2s(cs).filter(_ => true)
val c3s = new C3s(cs).filter(_ => true)
// val idontwork = new C2s(cs).filter(_ => true) //Doesn't work because `To` is abstract

c2s
c3s
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JW9ZTNtnS1afRYvhBHqtWw

Honestly your type model becomes pretty complicated. You should reconsider whether you really need all of those stuff (mixture of existentials, generics, higher kinds, type classes, variances, types...).

Comment: I hear your concern about the amount of complexity here and am open to ideas on how to simplify it. The real domain is as follows. `Config` is a hierarchy of serializable "project configurations". `Ci` is a hierarchy of "projects" created from a project configuration and additional information such as, for example, a delivery schedule. `Cis` are collections of `Ci` that have specific behaviors related to the type of what they hold. For example, for projects with a delivery schedule, one can filter to those that need to be delivered on a certain date. To boot, collections cannot extend `Seq`.

Comment: Though I have accepted @user's answer, your guidance has been very helpful and I'll find a way to award a bounty to this answer also.